# Debug =True didn't work on production site

Tags: django

I have a project deployed on production with gunicorn and nginx (may be info about environment will help to answer on my question). While building some new functionality i want to see full errors traceback. In `settings.py` i switched `debug=True` also i have specified `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['host.com','ip_adress']` but this mode isn't work. I expect that when i open 404 page i should see traceback. 
I know that enabling debug to true on production isn't a good way. But i need it.

Comment: have you restarted your gunicorn socket? ```sudo systemctl restart yourgunicornsocket```

Comment: @Steven it's helped. Thank you. If you provide your comment as answer i will flag it

Comment: "I know that enabling debug to true on production isn't a good way." Entirely true and you shouldn't. When you think you need it, you need to realize that you most likely don't actually need to do that. Most most cases there are other ways to achieve what you want to achieve - exposure can be dangerous and should be prevented at all costs.

Comment: @Nrzonline how i can prevent it ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/error-reporting/#errors

Comment: Also sentry can log 404's. If you want the 'debug page' of 404's, you can implement your own middleware that takes the requests, checks status and rebuild the debug behavior to a suitable solution which can be logged or mailed. Yes, this might be a bit of a hassle, but in most cases the better option instead of turning debug on. A minor mistake might e.g. expose API keys or what so ever, that would be quite painful.

Comment: @Nrzonline is i can hide my api keys variable when debug  turn to true ?

Comment: Well let me elaborate a bit further. Django has quite a detailed error page, displaying code and variables. If an error is triggered somewhere in the application, it is possible that it will expose code and variables that you do not expect. This might give the user insight in vulnerability  issues and exposure of sensitive data, you might not be aware of what is exposed to the client. It is simply dangerous to use DEBUG=True in production - that's all I want to warn you about. Custom middlewares are often a solution to these problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restart your gunicorn socket after making such changes:

```
sudo systemctl restart yourgunicornsocket
```